# ObjectPool in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I want to use an object pool in Kotlin and would prefer an open source library similar to [apache commons pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/examples.html). The only reason why I am not using apache commons pool is that it's borrow method is blocking. I want a pool with the following features

1. Set maxIdle objectes
2. Cleanup object that have been idle for too long
3. Creates object until the pool capacity is reached(If there is demand for more)
4. Does not allow users to leak objects

I have searched the internet for ideas and [this implementation](https://vasily-kirichenko.github.io/fsharpblog/object_pool) is very very close to what I want. The reason why I am not using is that it is based on experimental API. I am also not happy that I need to launch an infinite loop to handle object borrowing and recycling because if this loops fails the whole pool is dead. I prefer that methods `borrow()` and `recycle()` are executed based on demand for an object.

Lastly, I looked the the ObjectPool implemented in [Ktor](https://github.com/ktorio/ktor/blob/main/ktor-io/jvm/src/io/ktor/utils/io/pool/DefaultPool.kt) but I did not understand how the borrow and recycle are implemented. May someone explain how this the method `pushTop()` and `popTop()` work or just point me to the right literature about the concept being applied here. I think I can adopt this if I can figure out how the borrow and recycle methods work.

So what is my ask?

1. How can I adopt Ktor's `DefaultObject` pool to achieve my objectives mentioned above

Comment: Asking for a library is off-topic for StackOverflow. You should remove that part of your question.

Comment: You may also want to check out [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea for making Commons Pool offer a suspending borrow method. I didn't spend a lot of time reasoning this out, so I can't guarantee it totally makes sense. But my thinking is that since it already tries to unblock threads in the order they requested objects, it should be fine to have all the requests come in on the same thread and the coroutines will receive their objects in the same order they were requested. So, you can attach a single Thread Dispatcher to the single Pool. The downside is it ends up briefly suspending to swap threads even when the pool is not exhausted.

```
class SuspendingObjectPool<T>(private val sourcePool: ObjectPool<T>) : ObjectPool<T> by sourcePool {
    private val dispatcher = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().asCoroutineDispatcher()
    
    suspend fun borrowObjectSuspending(): T = withContext(dispatcher) { borrowObject() }
}

fun <T> ObjectPool<T>.asSuspendingObjectPool() = SuspendingObjectPool(this)
```

Comment: I did simple test on this and it makes the whole think single threaded.